# How do I connect Leica Summicron-M 1:2/50 E39 lens to Canon EOS 5D body?

Tags: lens, lens-adapter, old-lenses

Could anyone recommend what I need to buy in order to connect a Leica Summicron-M 1:2/50 E39 lens to a Canon EOS 5D body? Do I need a bayonet lens adaptor and if so please let me know which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such adapters, because the Leica M lenses have a registration distance that would put the lens *inside* the Canon's body if you wanted to achieve focus to infinity.  Canon's mount distance from the sensor is roughly twice that of a Leica M's mount from the sensor/film plane.  The distance the lens is held is part of the mount system design and is critical for the lens to focus properly.

To shove the M lens into the Canon body and hold it at the appropriate distance, you'd probably also collide with the SLR's mirrorbox--something M-mount rangefinders don't have.

The only digital camera bodies that you can easily adapt Leica-M mount lenses for are the mirrorless cameras: Sony NEX (E-mount), Fuji X, and Olympus/Panasonic micro four-thirds cameras, where the registration distance is smaller than that of Leica M, and where you can use simple ring adapters.  Be aware, however, that even though you can get the registration distance to work, there is still the issue of [sensor stack thickness](http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2014/06/sensor-stack-thickness-when-does-it-matter), particularly with wider fast lenses.

See also: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: that's interesting thanks. would sony RX1 body work?

Comment: or is it a fixed lens?

Comment: @SIa RX1 is a fixed-lens camera. One of the Sony A7 e-mount bodies is probably your only choice if you want full-frame. See: http://briansmith.com/sony-a7-a7r-lens-mount-adapters/. Most of the Sony e-mount and Fuji X cameras are 1.5x crop, while micro four-thirds is 2x crop, so the 50mm would have the FoV of a 75mm or 100mm would on film, respectively, on those bodies. On an A7, it'll have the same FoV that a 50mm would on film.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.  The flange distance of M mount is 27.8mm while EF mount is 44mm.  The lens would function as an extreme macro lens only on EF mount, so no one makes Leica M to Canon EF adapters.